# mod_rewrite for name fields

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am complete newbie in `mod_rewrite`, and I have been going through some sites reading how to handle this, all I could find was when the get variable was numbers and nothing about strings, and it turns out be over my head.

What I want to do is to rewrite `display.php?name=blahblah123` to `display/blahblah123`

Together with the answer, I would love some sites where I can build some grasp over `mod_rewrite` myself.

Thanks

Edit:

With more searching, I came up with this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^display/([a-z]+)$ display.php?name=$1 [L]
```

The code above works, but for some reason, The page I get has no CSS. The CSS I see included shows Hostgator's 404 page CSS. But HTML looks fine, so does the content and everything else. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to be clear, mod_rewrite is something that happens internally in apache.  I find that sometimes people do not understand what it does and doesn't do.  It will not take a url that you output and change it from

```
display.php?name=blahblah123
```

to
    display/blahblah123

It will however, allow someone to make a request from your site for display/blahblah123 and convert that to display.php?name=blahblah123, so that your display.php script can operate on it.

Rewrite rules require an understanding of regular expressions.  The better you understand regex the easier mod_rewrite will be for you.

As a beginner this article should help:  http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting/

For your specific question, I'd probably use:

```
RewriteRule ^display/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /display.php?name=$1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to put a "/" in front of the css file name.

```
<link rel=".." href="/style.css".
```

instead of

```
<link rel=".." href="style.css".
```